# $(this).val() not working in FireFox but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

This is  my problem. When I try to set the value of an input field in FireFox nothing happens. I don't get any errors. It simply just doesn't work. It is supposed to add two decimal places after the number. It works perfectly in Chrome. Here's my jQuery code...

```js
$('input.drawer').on('blur', function() {
  var number = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var n = number.toFixed(2);
  $(this).val(n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input tabindex="1" class="drawer f-right m-left w50 right-text" type="number" placeholder="$0.00" />
```

I've tried using `$(this).attr('value' n);` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `$(this).attr('value', n)` , you are missing a comma. All I can think of is that the method `.toFixed()` returns a string, while the input type is number, it might be expecting a number.

Comment: Or try a private window.

Comment: FF will not display trailing zeros (`document.getElementById('xxx').value = "42.10"`) would show `42.1` and it will truncate empty fractions (`.00`) - What you have does convert `42.125` to `42.13` (but its treated as invalid, add `step='any'`)

Comment: I tried using the code with the comma but it still doesn't work. I'll try converting the string to a number and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Alex K - How do I convert empty fractions? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @PatrickR: I don't think there is a way to influence the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around that seems to work in Firefox. I change the type of input to number on focus giving me the proper keypad on mobile but then change the type back to text on blur giving me to two decimal places. See the code below...

```
$('input.drawer').on('blur', function(){
    var number = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var n = number.toFixed(2);
    $(this).attr('type','text');
    $(this).val(n); 
});

$('input.drawer').on('focus', function(){ 
    $(this).attr('type','number');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So, it does "work", but Firefox simply formats the number differently, it truncates the `0`s. If you do

```
$(this).val(6.00);
```

you will see that it shows `6`.

If you do

```
$(this).val(6.50);
```

it will show `6.5` but also an error that it is not a valid value.

**What's with the error?**

The default `step` value of the input is `1` which makes Firefox only consider numbers as valid that are a multiples of that.

If you set `step="0.01"` then Firefox considers floating point numbers as valid.

**But the formatting is still incorrect**

However, this still won't show the decimals for whole numbers. I guess that's just how it is given that the spec doesn't seem to describe how the value should be formatted.

If the format is more important to you than the functionality of the number input, use a normal text input instead.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896
Adding a citation for the truncating.

Comment: @BrooklynWebDevelopers: Good find! Relevant comment from the thread: *"The problem is really that currency us not really "a number" in the sense that you can just put in a number in the usual way and have it look right.  It's a string that happens to look sort of like a number in some, but not all, cases.  The pre-1971 British currency, for example, makes this abundantly clear."*

Comment: So I guess I'm out of luck if I can't use type="text", right?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how firefox treats the number input type.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896

You can try text if that is an acceptable input type for you.

**Having found the above citation everything below is only interesting but not useful**

For example in Firefox vs Chrome check out
http://jsbin.com/coyuyipeca/edit?html,js,output

You'll see the value is indeed formatted correctly in the alert in FF but lost when pushed to the number field.  Change the input to

```
<input tabindex="1" class="drawer f-right m-left w50 right-text" type="text" placeholder="$0.00" />
```

and you'll see it work. Of course you will lose the benefits of the number field (notably mobile inputs) so it depends on how important that functionality is to you.

Note: One odd thing I note is if you set the input to

```
<input tabindex="1" class="drawer f-right m-left w50 right-text" type="number" step=".01" placeholder="$0.00" />
```

You can use the increment button and get decimals, it only seems to be lost when jQuery sets the value. Not sure if this is an issue with jQuery or with FF

Comment: *"Not sure what's going on, comments?"* Did you read my answer?

Comment: I sure did. What I'm saying is that you can directly set 
$(this).val(22.53);
and get the value. Did you explain this? Sorry if I missed it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but using type="text" is not an option because I need the mobile keypad to bring up numbers. By the way, I tried using step=".01" and that didn't work either.

Comment: @PatrickR it simply won't work the way you want to in Firefox, it's a known "bug" (or feature, they may never change it, it's how they interpret the standard) as I indicated at the top of my post. Wish I had better news.

Comment: @PatrickR
Consider this.
http://jsbin.com/coyuyipeca/edit?html,js,output

This makes the input a text, sets the value (which appears correctly), and 2.5 seconds later change it back to a number, you can see FF wipes out the decimal places, simply from the act of making it a number input.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me in the following jsfiddle:

```
<input tabindex="1" class="drawer f-right m-left w50 right-text" type="number" placeholder="0.00" />

$('input.drawer').on('blur', function() {
    var number = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var n = number.toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(n);
});
```

Which is your exact code. The only thing is you cannot input '$' symbol into a number field. That would fail. So for eg: '3.4512' gets truncated to '3.45' and set properly, but '$3.4512' just gets cleared when I try it.

https://jsfiddle.net/bz0os3kp/1/

Your code seems to work. It does truncate the trailing zeros in firefox however.

Comment: That's the problem, I need the trailing zeros in FireFox and by the way using type="text" is not an option, it must be number for the mobile capabilities.